# iTunes Home Sharing on Apple TV drops after a few minutes on Belkin N750

Tags: macbook-pro, appletv, home-sharing

Just bought an Apple TV and connected to my TV and all looks good. I'm having an issue with Home Sharing, however. The library is found, I play something from the library, it plays for about three minutes, then drops. I then cannot find the library in the "Computers" section of Apple TV. If I then quit iTunes and start it again, it shows up again on the Apple TV and I can start again only to be dropped three minutes later. I have seen some posts blaming the router not supporting Bonjour. I am on the phone now with Belkin.

Using: Apple TV connected via HDMI to a Panasonic LED TV, streaming from a MacBook Air 2010

I really think this is a Home Sharing issue.

Comment: Belkin found an update to the belkin router that fixed my issue.

You may want to update if you are not up to date.  The standard update check in the router settings did NOT find this update.

http://en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5359

Comment: Please re-post your comment as an answer to your own question. This will tell other users with the same problem that a solution has been found. Good work finding this!

Answer (score 1):

Working with Belkin we found an update to the Belkin router that fixed the issue. You may want to update if you are not up to date, version: 1.00.49. The standard update check in the router settings did NOT find this update.

en-us-support.belkin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5359